# How to use Physics2D.raycastAll

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to get all the hit results for a single ray by using `Physics2D.RayCastAll()`, but I can only get 2 hit results at most(The first hit result and the last.).

The 'viewpoint' is the start point, and the 'endPoint' is the end Point. There are some polygon colliders between these two points. I want to get all the hit positions.

```
Vector2 direction = endPoint - viewpoint.transform.position;
RaycastHit2D[] rayCastHits2D = Physics2D.RaycastAll(viewpoint.transform.position, direction, Mathf.Infinity);
```

What should I fix in the signature of the `RatcastAll()` method.

Comment: Are there `PolygonCollider`s as you stated or are there `PolygonCollider2D`? I'm pretty sure the `Physics2D.RaycastAll` needs `PolygonCollider2D` to hit them!

Answer (score 0):

Generate a 2D ray from viewpoint is weird. Are you sure the ray cast the objects?

I think you may change to use `Physics.raycastAll` with 3D colliders.

Answer (score 0):

Are there `PolygonCollider`s as you stated or are there `PolygonCollider2D`?

The `Physics2D.RaycastAll` needs `PolygonCollider2D` to hit them!

---

I son't think there is something wrong in your call of the method.

(there can't be something wrong with the `signature` ... it would not compile than)

---

Are you sure that all Colliders are between those 2 points?

Depending on what you want to do there you might rather want to use a 3D raycast using [Physics2D.GetRayIntersectionAll](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.GetRayIntersectionAll.html)

```
var ray = new Ray(viewpoint.transform.position, direction);
var raycastHits2d = GetRayIntersectionAll(ray);
```

Also note:

> Note that this function will allocate memory for the returned RaycastHit2D array. You can use [GetRayIntersectionNonAlloc](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.GetRayIntersectionNonAlloc.html) to avoid this overhead if you need to make such calls frequently.